# How to do combine multiple classes in one in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Basically, I want to be able to combine any number of classes, which, for example, will be defined in the same way as `mixinHobbies` or `mixinNotes`, and make TypeScript and IntelliSense not go crazy.

The order of mixins can be constant, but the number of ones that will be applied is varying.

```js
function mixinHobbies(Base: PersonCtor, hobbies: string[]) {
    return class extends Base {
        hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}

function mixinNotes(Base: PersonCtor, notes: string[]) {
    return class extends Base {
        notes = notes;
    }
}


interface PersonCtor {
    new (name: string, age: number): IPerson
}

interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const PersonWithHobbies = mixinHobbies(Person, ['drawing', 'reading']);
const PersonWithHobbiesAndNotes = mixinNotes(PersonWithHobbies, ['killlisted']);

const alex = new PersonWithHobbiesAndNotes('Alex', 18);

console.log(alex.hobbies);
```

`console.log(alex.hobbies);` throws `Property 'hobbies' does not exist on type '(Anonymous class)'`. IntelliSense also doesn't see the `hobbies` field.

Tho if executed, logs fine.

Something like this would be just perfect:

```js
function mixinPerson() {
    return new class {
        result = DefaultPerson;

        Hobbies(hobbies: string[]) {
            this.result = class extends this.result {
                hobbies = hobbies;
            }
            return this;
        }

        Notes(notes: string[]) {
            this.result = class extends this.result {
                notes = notes;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}


interface PersonCtor {
    new (name: string, age: number): IPerson
}

interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

class DefaultPerson implements IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const SuperPerson = mixinPerson()
.Hobbies(['drawing', 'reading'])
.Notes(['killlisted'])
.result;

const alex = new SuperPerson('Alex', 18);

console.log(alex.hobbies);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need your mixins to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `Base` constructor, so that the compiler does not widen it to `typeof Person` and forget about any additional structure:

```
function mixinHobbies<C extends new (...args: any) => Person>(Base: C, hobbies: string[]) {
  return class extends Base {
    hobbies = hobbies;
  }
}

function mixinNotes<C extends new (...args: any) => Person>(Base: C, notes: string[]) {
  return class extends Base {
    notes = notes;
  }
}
```

You can see that it works as desired:

```
const alex = new PersonWithHobbiesAndNotes('Alex', 18);
console.log(alex.hobbies); // no compiler error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWxgDxmAEnARrmAUwGcAeAYUULSkLABNjExCB3RACgDoeBDAJwDmxAFyJeYAJ4BKRAF4AfIgAKhfsQQKOAIV7FCY8gBpEACzwESY4lH6ZBAbQC6sgN4AoRIn6EoIfkgQADZ6TNS0DEy6+ogeXl7m+ERMcmYWyQDcnogAvu557qCQsAgo6JgAcnC0ZJThdIzMbJw8XALCYhIy8kqq6po6egaIxszVVog2dmCOLrHZPn4BiMGhVDQNUUPz8WM18nskWV55Be6YtPzAvBCEKmoaYORQcPw7TawcYLzIw1P2Jl4gmGYBAyFwamkYgAkn1Hvl3OcwJdrrdELCHqU4swfn9bPZjuJgWJQeC1FkCqtiEw4aUYMgAA5BQi-ZFMDH9JDY76-az4maEoEgsEQ-hZbIQBBTEDQV5fXF86aCQHE5giyHvLxQUwwYhcHl3VIGwlanV6oUHIWE06IyVgGz3TkAdRg2pwSRIB1QGGw6RIHFpYBMDgA5PR+LxWPYQyYQz5ePRoy4snaHYGXW6-cQAIIMKr7VLeyrjYgBzFgDOmd2WYjBkMAaxgQWbuto9BDydtUqg4mZaAOLHY6ddVazufo+f9IezfZjiAAjAAOaQpqVwZlcIJwQQcXh9riJGsroA)

Comment: No way to extend my second example?

Comment: Oh, you could maybe do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wzyerm), but if you need any declaration files for it it will probably not work (because the types are self-referential and using private names).  Or you could write up a full interface for what `mixinPerson()` returns, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxo31N), which is more portable but requires more explicit annotating and asserting.

Comment: Declaration files are a must, but thank you!